# Warning in Xcode 8: Instance method nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: xcode, notifications, ios10

I am trying to implement local notifications in iOS10, and so far [it is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954496/unusernotificationcenter-did-receive-response-with-completion-handler-is-never-c).

I get this warning around my delegate methods:

```
Instance method 'userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)'     
nearly matches optional requirement 'userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)'
of protocol 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'
```

As solution xcode suggests two options:
1.make it private
2.make it @nonobjc

Why is that? Why do I need to do it? And most important, how to make these methods work?

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 8 beta 6 introduced many Swift 3 changes, one of which is the `@escaping` keyword to mark closures that might be used after a method returns. Completion handlers are usually escaping closures, because you might show some information to the user, wait for feedback, and *then* call the completion handler – the method will return and keep a reference to the closure, rather than blocking.

I expect there will be an Xcode 8 GM issued in the next few hours, but right now Xcode *doesn't* insert the `@escaping` attribute where it's needed, which is probably what's causing your error. The two Fix-its being offered are red herrings, I'm afraid.

Try writing your method like this instead:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

Edit: Xcode 8 GM is now available, and correctly inserts `@escaping` when needed.

Comment: I installed xcode8 GM, still see sem issue, and it's not putting @escaping there, and when I put it - it says "unknown attribute escaping"

Comment: It's definitely correct; are you sure you're in Xcode 8?

Comment: pls see my image in the question (I am also using SWIFT2.3, instead of 3)

Comment: You rock dude, fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I have a line like this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {...}
```

Xcode gives me the same "nearly matches optional requirement" warning. Xcode 8.0 GM fixit gives me two choices to silence the warning. Add private keyword:

```
 private func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {...}
```

or add @nonobjc clause :

```
@nonobjc func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {...}
```

Either one shuts it up, but I am not sure which one is more preferable. When I tried @ escaping I get an error "@ escaping may only be used on 'parameter' declarations'.