# In my app latest notification is replacing previous one, how to stop this behavior?

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

In my app latest notification is replacing previous one, how to stop this behavior show that all notifications are shown in notification center until user clears.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    //center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if error == nil{
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Comment: see this and set notification's content identifier : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39396897/3901620

Comment: or remove this line from your code : UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

Comment: or remove this line from your code : UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 , not working